# Attaching electronics to a spinning surface without a battery

Tags: power, led, wireless

I am working with a friend to develop a spinning disk with LED lights on it.

The issue we are having is wrapping our minds around the idea of electronics on a surface that is spinning.

How do we interface with the LED lights without cords getting tangled around the spinning rod?

Is there a way to provide power to electronics on a spinning disk without having the battery directly on the disk?

Does this make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Search web for: "POV display", "Propellor clock", bob blick propeller clock. (The last being an early one that many people have built on - uses a motor winding as an alternator for the LEDs. ) .

Comment: These ones use an audio jack, very clever
http://code.google.com/p/povglobe/

Comment: @pim - Wonder how long that would last. I would guess not very long, as it appears that all the LEDs are on one side, moving the center of gravity way off center and putting a lot of stress on an audio jack that wasn't designed for this.  But yes, very clever!

Comment: @pim that is pretty sweet, I might give that a shot too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest tech, probably easiest method - Use brushes, just like for a motor. On the rotating part, you'd have the equivalent of slip rings, although the orientation would be flat rather than axial. The power thus obtained on the rotating part might have a bit of high frequency noise in it from the sliding contacts, so you'd want to be sure to get some filter caps on involved, probably near to where the power comes onto the board.

Comment: Slip rings are just the thing I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use contacts (e.g. carbon brushes, or copper) to press lightly against traces on the spinning disk and transfer power. Probably the simplest way. 
Or you could possibly use inductive coupling, e.g. something like a toroidal power coil on the base transfers power to a toroidal coil on the disk, although this would require more thought.

A good source of ideas would be the numerous POV displays everyone seems to be building (one row of spinning LEDs make a picture) I'm sure I have seen some inventive ways of supplying power (aside from battery) in a few of those. Google and You Tube will know more.

Comment: Inductive coupling is a nice idea, but then you have to worry about efficiency and rectifying the power once it gets on the board.

Comment: @MBraedley - I agree, although I thought efficiency may not be too important here. Just trying to throw another possible idea into the mix really.

Comment: Hopefully, it will be spinning at roughly 10000 rpm. But it may be a possibility.

Comment: you know, if you want to couple power magnetically, it's entirely possible to just plant some permanent magnets near the rotor, and then a coil on the rotor will act like an alternator. Although, technically speaking, the actual power for the rotating circuit would in this case be supplied mechanically from the motor driving the spinny thingy.

Answer (score 1):

The more expensive, and reliable (over the longer term) way to do this is with spinning mercury conductors.  These are devices, usually with multiple contact channels in which there is a little circular channel of liquid mercury around the spinning shaft that conducts electricity across the moving gap.  I'm not sure what these are called however, and they are a more expensive solution than brushes, or inductive solutions.  I did a search on these a while back, and seem to recall them being up in the $120 range, though I forget the specs I was looking for at the time. YMMV.

Comment: Oh, here you go:  "Brushless Slip Rings"... here's one company selling them.  http://www.mercotac.com/html/products.html (I'm not affiliated, fwiw)